# Setting up oauth for simple single-user desktop application

Tags: java, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I am writing a java desktop application for a single user that needs to access files in Google Drive in one specific google account which I want to hard code into the application. I am very confused about this whole OAuth 2.0 business which I am not familiar with it. Is there a simple way to login to the google apis when the user is known in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the scribe library, this should make your life easier.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scribe/info

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

Scribe provides an easy, extensible and bug-free way of OAuth-signing requests. But you have to check about their support for oauth 2.0: "OAuth 2.0 support is not going to get any more attention and may eventually be deprecated and dropped."
But there are several forks to support Google  OAuth 2.0

https://github.com/Kobee1203/scribe-java

https://github.com/bistri/scribe-java/

Comment: This helped a lot and I managed to get it to login, but now I can't figure out how to interface with the google drive api. Is there a way to use Scribe without having to write all of the http requests yourself?

Comment: You can do something like:

OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://graph.facebook.com/me");

//if you have parameters to pass use: 

addOAuthParameter("key", "value");

getOAuthService().signRequest(accessToken, request);

Response response = request.send();